# Can our mobile app execute code on install and update before/without being opened?

Tags: android, ios, events, mobile, xamarin.forms

We are developing an iOS and Android app in Xamarin.Forms and would like to do some registration and validation on initial install and subsequent updates without the user having to open the app. Is this possible?

Comment: Not on Android, thankfully. I can't speak for iOS.

Comment: In iOS you can't update the app automatically, user should initiate app update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not possible, without user interaction you can not do anything !

Comment: So I need the user to open the app in order to make sure we're still registered for push notifications, etc.? That's a bummer.

Comment: Once user interaction then you can config or register everyone as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

In Android you can react on **package updates** by writing a BroadcastReceiver and listening to MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED :

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true), IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionMyPackageReplaced })]
    public class PackageUpdateReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Package == "your.package.name") // Action MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED should only be called for your package - so this is actually not needed ...
            {
                // do some stuff ...
            }
        }
    }
```

The Attribute "BroadcastReceiver" will generate a manifest entry for you.

Note: If you want to use DependencyService within this method: Dont. It is not going to work because your app is not initialized at this stage - so the DependencyService will crash, bercause nobody called Xamarin.Forms.Init().

EDIT: To be more specific - The Receiver is obviously only called for allready installed apps - that means when a new Version of your app has been installed over an existing one.

This solution does not work for fresh installations.